# How can you use DAX USERELATIONSHIP with 2 or more dimensions in a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a measure in DAX (PowerBI) and currently I'm using a SWITCH statement to check the value of 'relationship' table to find out which relationship to use with my calendar dimension. This is all working fine, see below:-

```
My Measure = SWITCH(
    // Which calendar relationship should we use?
    MIN('Active Calendar Relationship'[Date Relationship]),

    "Some Date",
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Measures'[SomeField]),
        USERELATIONSHIP(
            'Calendar'[Key],
            'SomeFactTable'[SomeDateKey]
        )
    ),

    "Other Date",
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Measures'[SomeField]),
        USERELATIONSHIP(
            'Calendar'[Key],
            'SomeFactTable'[SomeDateKey]
        )
    ),

    // Default to 'Some Date'
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Measures'[SomeField]),
        USERELATIONSHIP(
            'Calendar'[Key],
            'SomeFactTable'[SomeDateKey]
        )
    )
)
```

My problem now is that I've also got a 'time of day' dimension, so I need to use the select time of day which I've got in another table where you can select the time of day relationship you want. The problem is in extending the code above to use multiple 'USERELATIONSHIP' statements, but as you can only use 'USERELATIONSHIP' in a 'CALCULATE' my only option is to somehow get every possible combination of the selected date/time values and build a huge SWITCH statement. Something a bit like this below (which hopefully you can see how big this might get):-

```
Some Measure = SWITCH(
    // Which 'calendar' relationship should we use?
    MIN('Active Calendar Relationship'[Date Relationship]),

    "Some Date",
    SWITCH(
        // Which 'time' relationship should we use?
        MIN('Active Time Relationship'[Time Relationship]),

        "Some Time",
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Measures'[SomeField]),
            USERELATIONSHIP(
                'Time'[Key],
                'Measures'[SomeTimeKey]
            ),
            USERELATIONSHIP(
                'Calendar'[Key],
                'Measures'[SomeDateKey]
            )
        ),

    "Other Time",
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Measures'[SomeField]),
            USERELATIONSHIP(
                'Time'[Key],
                'Measures'[OtherTimeKey]
            ),
            USERELATIONSHIP(
                'Calendar'[Key],
                'Measures'[SomeDateKey]
            )
        ),

        // Default to 'Some Date' and 'Some Time'
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Measures'[SomeField]),
            USERELATIONSHIP(
                'Time'[Key],
                'Measures'[SomeTimeKey]
            ),
            USERELATIONSHIP(
                'Calendar'[Key],
                'Measures'[SomeDateKey]
            )
        )
    ),

    "Other Date",
    SWITCH(
        // Which 'time' relationship should we use?
        MIN('Active Time Relationship'[Time Relationship]),

        "Some Time",
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Measures'[SomeField]),
            USERELATIONSHIP(
                'Time'[Key],
                'Measures'[SomeTimeKey]
            ),
            USERELATIONSHIP(
                'Calendar'[Key],
                'Measures'[OtherDateKey]
            )
        ),

    "Other Time",
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Measures'[SomeField]),
            USERELATIONSHIP(
                'Time'[Key],
                'Measures'[OtherTimeKey]
            ),
            USERELATIONSHIP(
                'Calendar'[Key],
                'Measures'[OtherDateKey]
            )
        ),

        // Default to 'Other Date' and 'Some Time'
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Measures'[SomeField]),
            USERELATIONSHIP(
                'Time'[Key],
                'Measures'[SomeTimeKey]
            ),
            USERELATIONSHIP(
                'Calendar'[Key],
                'Measures'[OtherDateKey]
            )
        )
    )

    and so on...
)
```

The only other way I thought might cut down on the code would be to create all the combinations as measures, but then there'd be lots of measures so its almost like just 'offloading' the problem. I'm no expert at DAX, but I've had a search and I'm struggling to find any other/better solutions to this problem. Hopefully there's another more efficient way of doing this than above...

help :-)

Answer (score -1):

The USERELATIONSHIP function is only needed when there are two or more relationships between two tables.
e.g. the calendar table and sales table have these two relationships

*Calendar[Date] --> Sales[OrderDate]* and

*Calendar[Date] --> Sales[FulfilmentDate]*

Only one relationship can be active at a time, you can tell which one it is by looking in the Model view in Power BI, the active relationship has a solid line and the deactivated relationship a dotted line.

By default DAX will use the active relationship. If you need to use a deactivated relationship then use the USERELATIONSHIP function in your DAX formulae.

https://dax.guide/userelationship/

So having both a calendar dimension table and a time dimension table each with only one relationship to your fact table means you can drop the USERELATIONSHIP function from your DAX function.

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately I do have many dates in my fact table and only 1 calendar dimension. I only listed the 'Some Date' and 'Other Date' as examples and to save space as I've got about 10 date fields and 10 time fields in the fact table. I've also got several 'staff' dimension key fields in my fact table too, so this problem quickly escalates even further than I listed...